# What museums and attractions in London offer interactive exhibits for blind people?

Tags: sightseeing, london, museums, accessibility

I'll be visiting London next year with my in laws, of which my father-in-law is blind. Since London is basically just wandering around and looking at things, our trip could get very boring very quickly for him.

I know some museums might have interactive exhibits (like things that you can touch), or maybe   free audioguides (not so important as we can read to him anyway + his English isn't spot on).

What museums have facilities for making things more interesting for blind visitors, and are there any other big sightseeing attractions that offer a more interactive experience for a blind person?

Answer (score 6):

VocalEyes is a company that provides audio-guide creation services and training to museum staff for visually impaired visitors. They have [a guide on what accessibility work they have done for museums (primarily ones in London)](http://www.vocaleyes.co.uk/page.asp?section=89&sectionTitle=Museums%20Galleries%20and%20Heritage%20Sites), which itself may not cover all facilities available at these or other museums but is a starting point for understanding the kind of accessibility for visually impaired users.